# How to efficiently copy row data from one Table to another in SQLite android

Tags: android

how do i efficiently copy a row data from one table to another table, where both of them are the same structure. i could go the much harder way of retrieving initial values from the row in the first table and then inserting to the second table. But i feel there is a more efficient way this can be done. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
insert into table1 select * from table2
```

Comment: hey, thanks, really appreciate it. but sorry, is this correct if i want to copy from a particular row.. insert into table1 select * from table2  where = rowID

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet code:

```
sqliteDataBase.execSQL("INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2");
```